# multivariate non-linear optimisation library for java similar to Matlab's solver GRG algorithm

Tags: java, optimization

I have been looking for a good optimization algorithm for almost a year now.

My problem consists of taking a matrix of observed values, lets call it 'M' and using a function 'F' which by transforming each of M's cells, one-by-one, produces another Matrix 'N'.

Then matrices 'M' and 'N' are compared using least square method and the distance between them should be minimized by changing the variables of 'F'.

There is an array of variables lets call it 'a' and a single variable 'b' which are used in the function F.

The variable 'b' is consistent between all of the calculations required to get the matrix 'N'.

The length of array 'a' depends on the number of rows; one number from array 'a' corresponds to each row.

So lets say to calculate the 3rd row of 'N' I use F on the value of each cell in the 3rd row of 'M' together with the variables a[3] and b.

To calculate the 4th row of N I calculate F with the value of each cell from the 4th row in M in turn together with a[4] and b.

And so on, and so on.

Once I calculate the whole of N, I need to compare it to M and minimize their distance by adjusting the array of variables a[] and the variable b.

I have been using Apache cmaes for smaller matrices but it doesn't work as well as matlab's solver on large matrices

EDIT

So ill try to describe this algorithmically as opposed to mathematically as that is my stronger side.

```
double[w,h] m //Matrix M
double[w,h] n //Matrix N
double[] hv // this is an array of constant hardcoded values
double[] a // this array is initialised to an initial guess
double b //also initialised to an initial guess
double total //target value, this value needs to be minimised
//w and h are constant

for(i=0; i<h; i++){
    for(j=0; j<w; j++)
        m[i,j] = getObservedValue[i,j] //observed values are not under my control
    }
}

for(i=0; i<h; i++){
    for(j=0; j<w; j++)
        n[i,j] = 0.75/1+e^(-b*(hv[i]-a[i]))+25 
    }
}

//once N is calculated initially using guesses for a[] and b

for(i=0; i<h; i++){
    for(j=0; j<w; j++)
        total = total + (m[i,j]*(m[i,j]-n[i,j])^2) //sum of square distances
    }
}
```

Now the objective is to minimise 'total'(distance between M and N) by finding the optimum values for a[] and b.
Perhaps if someone has done something similar they could point me to a library?
Or a quick demo of how i could find the optimal values my self?

Thanks very much for reading this,

Erik

Comment: Would be great if you could give us the equations or code, reading math from text hurts my brain.

Comment: According to [this answer on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116513/172496) this question is more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com